Wordpress website not loading
I downloaded an entire existing wordpress website from a filemanager. I also setup the database for it, by exporting/importing the existing database. I also modified the siteurl and home field in wp_options in https://localhost/my_project. But localhost does not load that website at all. It says can not reach site. And I'm not sure why. I also set up the right values in wp-config.php and I have no clue which other steps I could take. Any ideas?

What environment are you using to run the site locally?

@ChrisCox wamp server

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

WP stores URLs in a lot of different tables. You can either use a WP CLI command to search and replace the old URL to your new local URL, or use a plugin to do the same thing.
Don't just go do a blanket search-and-replace in phpMyAdmin or similar because the URLs are stored in serialized arrays in some places, and if the character count of the URLs differs the whole site breaks.

First can you run a test.php in your localhost? Also enable wp debug true, wp debug display true too. Also try to access other page urls.
